# SOAP XML response reults problems in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services, soap, response

Now i have used SOAP web service in my application and i am not getting the proper xml response results from the server, but the same web service is working fine in the Android side and they are getting the proper SOAP xml response. But it's not working in the iPhone side. So i donno which side having the problem, in the server side or client side(iPhone side only). I have tried ASHTTPRequest also, i am getting the same results.

this is the sample code for calling the web service using NSURL connection,

```
   NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                            @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             @"<soap:Body>\n"
                             @"<ViewMemberShipPackagesResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                             @"</ViewMemberShipPackagesResponse>\n"
                             @"</soap:Body>\n"
                             @"</soap:Envelope>\n"];


    NSString* urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://aaaaa.com/aaaaaa.asmx"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ViewMemberShipPackagesResponse" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [receiveData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {   
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [receiveData appendData:data];  
}   

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *urlDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receiveData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the  urlDataString is %@", urlDataString);
}
```

But i am not getting the proper soap xml response from the server. This sample output response from the server,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ViewMembershipPackagesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><ViewMembershipPackagesResult xsi:type="xsd:string">
```

`&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;soap:Body&gt;&lt;ViewMemberShipPackagesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"&gt;&lt;ViewMemberShipPackagesResult&gt;6&lt;/ViewMemberShipPackagesResult&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;5&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;1 Month Package&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;1 Month&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$29.99&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;Test&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;/Package&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;6&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;1 Month Package with Multiple Locations&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;1 Month&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$89.99&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;This pacakge to have&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;`

```
/Package&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;7&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;12 Month Test Package&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;12 Months&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$360.00&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;12 Month Package&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;/Package&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;4&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Andy Test Package&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;12 Months&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$49.99&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;Test package for a year&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;/Package&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;2&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Golden Package&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;6 Months&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$80.00&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;/Package&gt;&lt;Package&gt;&lt;ID&gt;1&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Premium Package&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;DateSpan&gt;12 Months&lt;/DateSpan&gt;&lt;Price&gt;$120.00&lt;/Price&gt;&lt;Description&gt;It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;/Package&gt;&lt;/ViewMemberShipPackagesResponse&gt;&lt;/soap:Body&gt;&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;</ViewMembershipPackagesResult></ViewMembershipPackagesResponse>  </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>.
```

Please guide me.

THanks!

Comment: can you tell me how you resolved this..?

Answer (score 1):

change  this :

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

      NSString * urlDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [receiveData mutableBytes] length:[receiveData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"the  urlDataString is %@", urlDataString);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that one, but no luck. still having the same results.